# Issue with java 8 api stream. Need to filter non existent keys

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a list:

```
List<String> myList = Arrays.asList("key1", "key2", "key3");
```

and a map:

```
Map<String, String> myMap = Map.of("key1","VALUE1", "key2", "VALUE2");
```

When I do the following:

```
myList.stream().map(i->myMap.get(i)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I have the following output:

```
[VALUE1, VALUE2, null]
```

How can I do my logic so that I have something like a String "Map does not contain such key" instead of "null" in my output?

Comment: Doesn't `null` already have such information for you?

Comment: Do you want your output list to contain a "Map does not contain such key"  value instead of null? Seems strange to me.

Comment: I agree with @Eran here - mapping to this default string is probably not what you should be doing. Instead, you can either filter the `null`s out, or throw an exception with that text as the exception message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `.getOrDefault(key, defaultValue)` method of the `Map` class. Here's an example:

```java
String defaultText = "Map does not contain such key";
myList.stream().map(i -> myMap.getOrDefault(i, defaultText)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make the following change to [UtkuÖzdemir's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64426623/1552534) excellent answer.

Record the key along with the text, that way, you know exactly which key was missing.

```
List<String> myList = Arrays.asList("key1", "key2", "key3", "key4", "key5");
Map<String, String> myMap = Map.of("key1","VALUE1", "key2", "VALUE2");
List<String> results = myList.stream()
             .map(i-> myMap.getOrDefault(i, "Doesn't exist for '" + i + "'"))
             .collect(Collectors.toList());

results.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Prints

```
VALUE1
VALUE2
Doesn't exist for 'key3'
Doesn't exist for 'key4'
Doesn't exist for 'key5'
```